# How do I display the multiplication and division symbol using pytexit?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, latex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHp6K.png)

For example, I want a multiplication sign between 5/2 and the brackets. Also a division sign between 10 and 4.

I also have another question, how do I remove the brackets around 68 and 87? thank you

Comment: Read a good book about LaTeX or HTML5

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I think OP's solution is not limited by the knowledge of latex but also by **how** to implement it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question here is how to convert a unicode string into a latex output as a latex editor/compiler system would do. The best package for that is [pylatexenc](https://pypi.org/project/pylatexenc/)

To answer your question:

```py
from pylatexenc.latex2text import LatexNodes2Text
from pylatexenc.latexencode import UnicodeToLatexEncoder

# To convert some latex unicode input to actual latex output
in_expr_unicode = r"""5\div2\times(68+87)-10\div4"""
out_latex = LatexNodes2Text().latex_to_text(in_expr_unicode)
print('          The math formula: ', out_latex)

# To convert the latex string back to unicode printable string (for use in some latex editor)
u = UnicodeToLatexEncoder(unknown_char_policy='replace')
print('The latex editor input was: ', u.unicode_to_latex(out_latex))
```

The output would be:

```sh
          The math formula:  5÷2×(68+87)-10÷4
The latex editor input was:  5{\textdiv}2{\texttimes}(68+87)-10{\textdiv}4
```

Comment: so, for division, I have used `\div` and for multiplication I have used `\times`. In case I have made a mistake in the expression, correct it; I intend to capture the method!

Answer (score 0):

for removing brackets you can describe the initial expression as below:

```
py2tex('5/2*(68+87)-10/4')
```

[image]

I don't see any help within this package to show the multiplication or division sign.

Comment: OP also wants this: `I want a multiplication sign between 5/2 and the brackets. Also a division sign between 10 and 4`, which means we need a more robust package!